# Well positioned on Google w/ Laravel multilanguage?

Tags: laravel, localization, seo, positioning

I have a Laravel application with 3 languages (es, en, fr) that work perfectly.

Even so, I think it is only being positioned in Spanish, because when I search on Google sentences of the text in Spanish my website appears, but it doesn't happen when I try it with the other languages. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You migth want to try adding some alternate links to the pages with the same content on the other languages like so:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="{your_href_to_the_same_page_on_en}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="{your_href_to_the_same_page_on_fr}" />
```

Also consider looking through [this article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) about SEO for multilanguage sites.